# Joining multiple tables in Criteria ruins the expected output

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, criteria, specifications

I am trying to make a dynamic search in multiple tables.

When I join **ONLY** one table I get the expected output.
When I join all the tables I get only half of the result or even none. Even If I dont include the **Predicates** in the **criteriaBuilder.or();** just declaring the **JOINS** breaks the code.

**Entity:**

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
   
   //Other fields...
  
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "imageInfo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<GenreImageInfoMEntity> genres;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "imageInfo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<KeywordImageInfoMEntity> keywords;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "imageInfo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<LocationImageInfoMEntity> locations;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "imageInfo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<PersonImageInfoMEntity> persons;
```

**Join Entity:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "genre_image_info_mapping",schema = "public")
public class GenreImageInfoMEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_genre_id")
    GenreEntity genre;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_image_info_id")
    ImageInfoEntity imageInfo;

}
```

**Joined Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "genre",schema = "public")
public class GenreEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;
}
```

The other 3 Entities looks the same.

**Specification**

This way work correctly:

```
    private  Specification<ImageInfoEntity> fullSearch(String search) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {

            Join<ImageInfoEntity, GenreImageInfoMEntity> joinG = root.join(ImageInfoEntity_.GENRES);
            String searchFinal = "%" + Utility.unaccent(search.toLowerCase()) + "%";

            Predicate genrePredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinG.get(GenreImageInfoMEntity_.GENRE).get(GenreEntity_.NAME))),searchFinal);
            return criteriaBuilder.or(genrePredicate);

        };
    }
```

This way I get 0 results.

```
    private  Specification<ImageInfoEntity> fullSearch(String search) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {

            Join<ImageInfoEntity, GenreImageInfoMEntity> joinG = root.join(ImageInfoEntity_.GENRES);
            Join<ImageInfoEntity, LocationImageInfoMEntity> joinL = root.join(ImageInfoEntity_.LOCATIONS);
            Join<ImageInfoEntity, PersonImageInfoMEntity> joinP = root.join(ImageInfoEntity_.PERSONS);
            Join<ImageInfoEntity, KeywordImageInfoMEntity> joinK = root.join(ImageInfoEntity_.KEYWORDS);

            String searchFinal = "%" + Utility.unaccent(search.toLowerCase()) + "%";

            Predicate genrePredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinG.get(GenreImageInfoMEntity_.GENRE).get(GenreEntity_.NAME))),searchFinal);
            Predicate personPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinP.get(PersonImageInfoMEntity_.PERSON).get(PersonEntity_.SEARCH_NAME))),searchFinal);
            Predicate keywordPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinK.get(KeywordImageInfoMEntity_.KEYWORD).get(KeywordEntity_.KEYWORD))),searchFinal);
            Predicate locationPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinL.get(LocationImageInfoMEntity_.LOCATION).get(LocationEntity_.NAME))),searchFinal);
            Predicate locationHUNPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinL.get(LocationImageInfoMEntity_.LOCATION).get(LocationEntity_.HUN_NAME))),searchFinal);
            Predicate locationENGPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinL.get(LocationImageInfoMEntity_.LOCATION).get(LocationEntity_.ENG_NAME))),searchFinal);
            Predicate photographerPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(ImageInfoEntity_.PHOTOGRAPHER).get(PersonEntity_.ABC_NAME))),searchFinal);
            Predicate ownerPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(ImageInfoEntity_.OWNER))),searchFinal);
            return criteriaBuilder.or(genrePredicate,personPredicate,keywordPredicate,locationPredicate,locationENGPredicate,locationHUNPredicate,ownerPredicate,photographerPredicate);
            

        };
    }
```

**Other specification:**

```
    public Specification<ImageInfoEntity> build(FilterImageInfoDto filterImageInfoDto) {

        List<Specification<ImageInfoEntity>> specifications = new ArrayList<>();

        if(filterImageInfoDto.getSearch()!= null){
            specifications.add(fullSearch(filterImageInfoDto.getSearch()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getSizeX()!= null){
            specifications.add(isSizeXEq(filterImageInfoDto.getSizeX()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getSizeY()!= null){
            specifications.add(isSizeYEq(filterImageInfoDto.getSizeY()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getCategory()!= null){
            specifications.add(isCategoryEq(filterImageInfoDto.getCategory().getId()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getUploadDate()!= null){
            specifications.add(isUploadDateEq(filterImageInfoDto.getUploadDate()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getCaptureYear()!= null){
            specifications.add(isCaptureYearEq(filterImageInfoDto.getCaptureYear()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getTechnics()!= null  && !filterImageInfoDto.getTechnics().isEmpty() ){
            specifications.add(isTechnicsEq(filterImageInfoDto.getTechnics()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getMaterials()!= null && !filterImageInfoDto.getMaterials().isEmpty()){
            specifications.add(isMaterialsEq(filterImageInfoDto.getMaterials()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getGenres()!= null&& !filterImageInfoDto.getGenres().isEmpty()) {
            specifications.add(isGenreEq(filterImageInfoDto.getGenres()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getPersons()!= null && !filterImageInfoDto.getPersons().isEmpty()){
            specifications.add(isPersonEq(filterImageInfoDto.getPersons()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getPhotographers()!= null && !filterImageInfoDto.getPhotographers().isEmpty()){
            specifications.add(isPhotographerEq(filterImageInfoDto.getPhotographers()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getLocations()!= null && !filterImageInfoDto.getLocations().isEmpty()){
            specifications.add(isLocationEq(filterImageInfoDto.getLocations()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getKeywords()!= null && !filterImageInfoDto.getKeywords().isEmpty()){
            specifications.add(isKeywordLike(filterImageInfoDto.getKeywords()));
        }
        if(filterImageInfoDto.getHolders()!= null && !filterImageInfoDto.getHolders().isEmpty()){
            specifications.add(isHolderEq(filterImageInfoDto.getHolders()));
        }

        return  specifications.stream()
                .reduce(Specification::and)
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

What am I missing ?

I have tried breaking it into different functions but nothing helps.

Comment: Use Left Joins, If you want to include all rows from the ImageInfoEntity table regardless of whether there are matching rows in the related tables, you should use left joins instead of inner joins. This way, the query will return all ImageInfoEntity rows, with null values for columns from the joined tables where no match is found.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com Thank you for commenting. I have tried all variations of JOIN but  none of them solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
Predicate personPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(**joinP.get(PersonImageInfoMEntity_.PERSON).get(PersonEntity_.SEARCH_NAME)**)),searchFinal);
```

In the above code snippet:

**joinP.get(PersonImageInfoMEntity_.PERSON).get(PersonEntity_.SEARCH_NAME)**

Makes a JOIN. But these types of JOINs are normal JOINs, which limits the output.

So basically, by joining manually on every get, you can specify the join type.

```
Join<GenreImageInfoMEntity, GenreEntity> joinGGenre = joinG.join(GenreImageInfoMEntity_.GENRE, JoinType.LEFT);

Predicate genrePredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.function("unaccent", String.class, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinGGenre.get(GenreEntity_.NAME))),searchFinal);
```

Comment: Actually you were using inner join that reduces your result set. If you use left join or right join then it wont happen.